# How to represent a video as a mathematical function?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out how one represents a video as a function.

I would declare it this way:

$f: \lbrace 1,...,n\rbrace \times\lbrace 1,...,m\rbrace \times [0,T] \rightarrow \lbrace 0,...,255\rbrace^3$

where T is the length of the Video (in seconds)
n is the number of vertical pixels and m the number of horizontal pixels

for each time and each pixel the pixel will be set up with a rgb coded light.

Is this version similar to what people use when analysing videos or pictures (programming panorama mode or sorts)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you usually simply consider a video a multidimensional array with $w \times h \times t \times c$ coordinates, where the parameters are screen width, screen height, time and color  component

Comment: and if it needs to be as a function?

Comment: When you say "function", do you mean "a mathematical expression that I can evaluate"? Or why do you need to represent it as a function?

Comment: a function meaning something like $f$ with $f(x)=ax+b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncompressed video is a sequence of image frames. An image frame is a 2D array of numbers (typically integers that represents some quantization). Each pixel is represented by a value in a color space. You can have multiple color spaces such as RGB color space, YUV color space, HSL color space etc., and there is another parameter which is the color depth. This determines how many bits is used for representing color. For eg: an 8-bit RGB color space uses 8 bits for each component of color R, G and B. There are encodings that use an Alpha channel to indicate color transparency (eg: 8-bit RGBA where 8 bits is used for each color channel and the alpha channel).

Since video has a lot of redundancy in data, it is typically compressed. There are many schemes used for this such as Discrete Cosine Transform, Wavelet Transform etc., that are applied at a block level. A block may be $256 \times 256$ pixels (for instance). Video typically uses some form of differential coding because the frames don't change much between time instants. So, you may find compression schemes representing the information as a delta between successive frames and encoding the deltas.

At the end of the day, there is no single way to represent video as a mathematical function. You can choose the method based on what your goals are. Video is typically represented as a discrete function of time.

You can read through any Digital Signal Processing or Image Processing textbook to understand commonly used representations.